Celery sending the process id of parent worker rather than worker process in the Events dispatched
I am working on a celery monitoring tool. For this, I am recording events from celery.events.receiver.EventReceiver.
The data that is being sent looks like this (removed unnecessary info for brevity)
{... "pid": 26342, "type": "task-received", ...}
{... "pid": 26342, "type": "task-started", ...}

Now, the issue is that the actual worker pool process that is running the code has pid 26391. The pid 26342 is of the parent worker.
My question is, is this a bug or intentional for monitoring purposes? If intentional, can anyone kindly explain the reason for it?
Note: Using default prefork pool.
Normally, I would have expected the pool process pid instead of parent worker pid.

Main Celery worker manages the worker processes, so basically main worker IS what you call the "pool process".
